# Flash CS5: combining bold and regular text in a textfield?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fonts, flash-cs5

I am trying to combine bold and regular text in a textfield but how do I embed an font family and not just a single style of a font?

See example of how I embedded a font, you can only choose one style: "regular", "bold", "italic" or "bold italic" at once:

[image]

However, when you try to embed the text (via the IDE settings or actionscript) how do you set the font to be the entire family?

[image]

See: family only allows "ArialRegular" and not "Arial", the entire family?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embed each part of the family as a separate font and if you are utilizing TextFormat objects, supply the additional startIndex/endIndex parameters to the setTextFormat function call to apply your bold text to a given range of characters. Alternatively, with both variants embedded, use HTML or a StyleSheet to specify each type as appropriate.

Comment: +1 for the right answer, even though you forgot the key step: Praying. Fonts are a little unreliable in flash!

Comment: I'm all for praying, they are really unreliable.